# Como acceder a varias filas en SQL desde php

Tags: php, sql

Cuando hago una consulta a una tabla en la que me salen como resultado dos filas por ejemplo:

```
$sql= "SELECT id, nombre, apellido FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = 'Juan'";
$res = $db->query($sql) or die("error: ".$sql);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

y me sale este resultado;

```
id: 1 nombre: Juan apellido: Rodriguez
id: 5 nombre: Juan apellido: Herrero
id: 8 nombre: Juan apellido: Fuentes
```

Como puedo acceder a todos esos datos desde php? porque solo puedo acceder al primer registro usando `$row['id']` `$row['nombre']` `$row['apellido']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu variable `$row` guarda TODOS los resultados, lo que deberias hacer es algo asi :

```
$res = $db->query($sql) or die("error: ".$sql);
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $results[] = $row;
}
```

Y para obtener todos los datos

```
foreach ($results as $result){
   print_r($result['id']);
   print_r($result['nombre']);
}
```

Como quieres acceder a traves de un "indice" a tu objecto bastaria con esto :

```
$array_final = array();
foreach ($results as $result){
   $array_final[] = $result;
}

for ($i=0; $i < count($array_final); $i++) { 
   print_r($array_final[$i]['nombre']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad se puede sacar los datos desde el resulset:

```
$res = $db->query($sql) or die("error: ".$sql);
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   print_r($row['id']);
   print_r($row['nombre']);
}
```

Si solo vas a leer los datos una vez, creo que de esta manera te puede servir, en cambio si quieres leer varias veces el resultado de la select, es mejor como dice el compañero @sioesi.

También un ResulSet se puede resetear con `mysqli_data_seek($res, 0);` [mysqli_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Comment: No hay ninguna manera de seprarlo en un array "bidimenisonal" tal que así: `$miarray[1]['apellido']` y `$miarray[2]['apellido']` ?

Comment: @PavloB. editare mi respiuesta para conseguir lo que quieres